# Visual svg editor

Tags: svg, editor

I need to create and edit diagrams in svg format, are there any svg editors with a visual interface?

I am currently using Notepad++, there must be a better way!

Comment: Take a look at inkscape

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this for desktop (actually it is ported to most of platforms) http://inkscape.org/ 
or this for online http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1771/trunk/editor/svg-editor.html

Comment: Method Draw is just great: http://editor.method.ac